# How can I set -webkit-mask-box-image through javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, mask

I have a div with `id="container'` that I want to set a `-webkit-mask-box-image` for. Currently I have this through css:

```
#container
{
-webkit-mask-box-image: url('masks/4.png');
width:235px;
height:300px;
}
```

But I want to set the css through javascript, because the mask should change each hour.

I have tried:

```
document.getElementById("container").setAttribute("style", "-webkit-mask-box-image: url('masks/"+hour+".png'); width:235px; height:300px;");
```

But that doesn't work. How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set in JQuery by below Line of Code, Here is **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hknbma22/)**

```
$('#container').css('-webkit-mask-box-image',"url('masks/4.png')")
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
document.getElementById("container").style.setAttribute("-webkit-mask-box-image", "url('masks/"+hour+".png')");
document.getElementById("container").style.setAttribute("width","235px");
document.getElementById("container").style.setAttribute("height","300px");
```